# Approaching the volume under a gaussian function using concentric cylinders

Tags: probability, analysis, normal-distribution, volume

im trying to wrap my brain around a question ive been given by a friend.
Given the distribution $f(0)^2 \cdot e^\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}$, the goal is to calculate the volume between the function and the x-y Plane.
The way this is supposed to be done is to use concentric cylinders - which brings me to my question. The problem states: Show that the volume of such a cylinder is given by $V(r) = f(0)^2 \cdot e^\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\cdot 2\pi\cdot r \cdot \Delta r$
It then continues on to show that the entire volume can be calculated using the following integral:
$\int_0^{\infty} f(0)^2 \cdot e^\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}\cdot 2\pi\cdot r dr$

I can do the integral and i understand the idea behind it. What i dont understand is the way the initial formula is set up. This whole task is done to derive some version of the normal distribution, which i have never seen to have an $f(0)$ inside of the formula.

TL;DR: whats happening with $V(r)$? why does this work to approximate said volume?

Thanks alot

Comment: The $f(0)$ just the constant needed to rescale the function $e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ to be a probability density and is $\frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma}$ since $e^{-0}=1$. You square it because you are working in two dimensions (and also have $r^2 = x^2+y^2$)

Comment: We are partitioning the $x-y$ plane into infinitely many concentric annulus. Since we are plotting the pdf in the $z$ dimension, the value of the pdf is the height of the cylinder while the annulus are the base of the cylinder. For the annulus with inner radius $r$ and outer radius $r + \Delta r$, we have the area $\pi[(r + \Delta r)^2 - r^2] = \pi[2r \cdot \Delta r + (\Delta r)^2] \approx 2\pi \cdot r \cdot \Delta r $ with the higher order term $(\Delta r)^2$ dropped. So this gives area of the infinitesimal annulus, which is the area of the base of the cylinder.